# Getting touch screen to work on a drawing canvas - HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently made a project where you can draw with simple tools, but one thing I cannot seem to figure out is getting it to work on any general touch screen device, like a touch screen laptop or a phone. Is there any way to do this in a website? If so, how?
HTML:

```
  <section class="container">
    <div id="toolbar">
      <h1>SKETCH</h1>
      <label for="stroke">stroke</label>
      <input id="stroke" name="stroke" type="color">
      <label for="lineWidth">line width</label>
      <input id="lineWidth" name='lineWidth' type="number" value="5">
      <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
    </div>
    <div class="drawing-board">
      <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
        const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
        const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
        const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

        canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

        let isPainting = false;
        let lineWidth = 5;
        let startX;
        let startY;
        
        toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        });
        toolbar.addEventListener('change', e => {
            if(e.target.id === 'stroke') {
                ctx.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
            }
            if(e.target.id === 'lineWidth') {
                lineWidth = e.target.value;
            }
        });
        const draw = (e) => {
            if(!isPainting) {
                return;
            }
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvasOffsetX, e.clientY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            isPainting = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
        });
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
            isPainting = false;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath();
        });
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
```

I have tried changing stuff like mouse to things like touch, just thought it was a plausible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, just like the `mouseup` and `mousedown` there's also touch events for mobile: `touchstart`, `touchend`, and `touchmove`. The only difference for this use case would be instead of accessing the position of the event through `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`, the event in a `TouchEventHandler` gives you access to the array of `touches` that were made. Each item has `clientX`, `clientY` and the other values you'd expect.

For example:

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches?.[0]
    if (!touch) {
        return
    }
    // you can treat `touch` as you would the mouse event in `mousedown`
    isPainting = true
    startX = touch.clientX
    startY = touch.clientY
    
})
```

`touchend` would mimic your `mouseup` event and `touchmove` would mimic your `mousemove` event, just using `touch` instead of the mouse event.